# Binding to the selected TabItem content

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, tabitem

I have a Window with two controls: control1 is a control that has a bunch of buttons that execute `RoutedCommands`; the second control is a `TabControl` that is bound to a list of documents. The `TabControl` `ContentTemplate` is a user control, control2, that has a `ListView`. I would like to bind the `DataContext` of control1 to the `ListView` of control2 of the selected tab. Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="deleteme.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:deleteme"
    xmlns:sc="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sc:ArrayList x:Key="Tabs">
            <local:Document Name="doc1" />
            <local:Document Name="doc2" />
            <local:Document Name="doc3" />
        </sc:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <local:control1 DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Tabs}" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:control2 />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="deleteme.control1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:deleteme"
    x:Name="control">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Actions}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="actionButton" Content="{Binding Path=Text}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=actionButton_IsEnabled}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext}" Click="actionButton_Click" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="deleteme.control2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The reason that I want to bind the `ListView` of control2 to control1 is twofold: I can use `ListView.SelectedItem` as the parameter to `RoutedCommand.Execute`, and I can use the `ListView` as the `CommandTarget` so that I can handle actions that pertain to a document in control2.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to bind the `ListView` of control2 to control1. Actually, its more likely that I am approaching the problem incorrectly as I'm new to WPF. If anyone has a suggestion, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in terms of binding the listview, think in terms of binding to the data instead. I assume that you are intending the data to be used between the two user controls; in which case, as long as you have the DataContext higher up the tree then both controls can get access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can bind to the data easily enough. I don't want to share the data between the controls though--I want to be able to call RoutedCommand.Execute from control1 using control2 as the CommandTarget.